# Meteor: subscribing to collection not giving any data

Tags: meteor, publish, subscribe

I am unfortunately having another issue with Meteor after my last one was cleared up... I suspect I'm missing some thinking here but I'm not sure.

I'm trying to create a collection to hold info of users according to their Steam profiles. I defined a collection like this in my lib/collections.js:

`userInfoList = new Mongo.Collection('publicUserInfo');`

Whenever a user signs in with their Steam account via oauth, this function is called in my lib/server/common.js:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
    var steamId = user.services.steam.id;
    var result = getInfoOfUser(steamId); // Function that returns a json with a SteamID's info from Steam API

    var personaNameU = result.displayName;
    var profileLinkU = result.link;
    var avatarUrlU = result.avatar;

    userInfoList.insert({userId: user._id, steamId64: steamId, personaName: personaNameU, profileLink: profileLinkU, avatarUrl: avatarUrlU});

    console.log('Created User with id ' + user._id + ' and Steam link ' + profileLinkU);

    return user;
  }
);
```

The console message successfully fires with the profile link, so I know the function is working fine. The document should be inserted into the collection... it doesn't throw any errors. I then try to publish the data and subscribe to it in my profile.js page:

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
    Meteor.subscribe('userInfoPublic');

    Template.profile.helpers({
        'getName': function(){
            var username = userInfoList.find().personaName; // Only works when one object is passed... once I change the publish requirements only one will be passed
            return username;
        },
        'getPic': function(){
            var avatarUrl = userInfoList.find().avatarUrl; // Same as above
            return avatarUrl;
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.publish('userInfoPublic', function(){
        return userInfoList.find();
    })
}
```

Note I am only returning userInfoList.find() temporarily for debugging... but both it and userInfoList.find({userId: this.userId}) don't return anything. I check in the Chrome console with userInfoList.find(), but it returns an empty result. Is there some methodology I'm not understanding here with collections? Thanks.

EDIT: I should've clarified the Console can *see* that the collection exists, it just doesn't have any entries.

Comment: @Alex028502 yes... I believe my error is calling an async function right before inserting it... I don't think the user is actually being inserted to the DB. Am trying to fix

Comment: Have you checked if the data is actually inserted into the server-side db?